# Is there a difference between a Picard stack and a stack of symmetric monoidal categories?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, ct.category-theory

It seems to me that Picard stacks as defined by Deligne and used in algebraic geometry are stacks of symmetric monoidal categories.   Am I missing something? Is there a difference between the two notions?  The Picard stack I am interested in shows up in symplectic toric geometry ([arXiv:0908.2783v2[math.SG]](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.2783) )

Comment: The difference is obviously not in the stacky part, bur in the categorical part. A Picard category is a symmetric monomial category where all morphisms are invertible.

Comment: Thanks.  So a Picard category is a symmetric monoidal groupoid?

Comment: I think the point is that all *objects* are invertible (with respect to the monoidal structure). 

Comment: @Eugene: Your question has already been answered on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24912/what-are-picard-categories-where-can-i-learn-more-about-them-and-why-should-i-c

Comment: In modern terms, a Picard category is some flavour of 'abelian' 2-group.

Comment: Konrad is correct, I missed objects, in a Picard groupoid objects and morphisms are invertible.