# Explicit description of the tensor product of symmetric monoidal categories / Picard groupoids

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

$\newcommand{\lax}{\mathsf{lax}}\newcommand{\oplax}{\mathsf{oplax}}\newcommand{\str}{\mathsf{str}}\renewcommand{\S}{\mathbb{S}}\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}\newcommand{\Hom}{\mathrm{Hom}}$We have tensor products $\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}$ of commutative monoids and abelian groups, determined by requiring natural bijections of the form
\begin{align*}
\Hom_{\mathsf{CMon}}(A\otimes_\mathbb{N}B,C) &\cong\Hom_{\mathsf{CMon}}(A,\mathbf{Hom}_{\mathsf{CMon}}(B,C)),\\
\Hom_{\mathsf{Ab}}(A\otimes_\mathbb{Z}B,C) &\cong\Hom_{\mathsf{Ab}}(A,\mathbf{Hom}_{\mathsf{Ab}}(B,C))
\end{align*}
to hold. Similarly, it has been shown that there is a tensor product $\otimes_{\mathbb{F}}$ in the $2$-category of symmetric monoidal categories, determined by requiring a natural isomorphism of categories of the form
\begin{equation}
\mathsf{SymMonFun}^{\mathsf{strong}}(\mathcal{C}\otimes_\mathbb{F}\mathcal{D},\mathcal{E})
\cong
\mathsf{SymMonFun}^{\mathsf{strong}}(\mathcal{C},\mathsf{SymMonFun}^{\mathsf{strong}}(\mathcal{D},\mathcal{E})),\tag{1}
\end{equation}
or, equivalently, by asking for a natural isomorphism of categories
$$
\mathsf{SymMonFun}^{\mathsf{strong}}(\mathcal{C}\otimes_\mathbb{F}\mathcal{D},\mathcal{E})
\cong
\mathsf{SymMonFun}^{\mathsf{strong},\mathsf{bil}}(\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{D},\mathcal{E}),
$$
where the objects of the category on the RHS are “bilinear symmetric monoidal functors $F\colon\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{E}$”, coming equipped with natural families of isomorphisms
\begin{align*}
F(A,B\otimes_{\mathcal{D}}B') &\overset{\sim}{\dashrightarrow} F(A,B)\otimes_{\mathcal{E}}F(A,B'),\\
F(A\otimes_{\mathcal{C}}A',B) &\overset{\sim}{\dashrightarrow} F(A,B)\otimes_{\mathcal{E}}F(A',B),\\
F(\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{C}},B) &\overset{\sim}{\dashrightarrow} \mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{E}},\\
F(A,\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{D}}) &\overset{\sim}{\dashrightarrow} \mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{E}}.
\end{align*}
However, both proofs that I'm aware of―the first given by [Hyland–Powell](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82433091.pdf) using abstract $2$-categorical machinery and [the second](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.4550) by Gepner–Groth–Nikolaus via $\infty$-categories–are non-constructive. There's also [Schmitt's work](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.0324), in which they construct a tensor product $\otimes_{\mathbb{F}}'$ characterised by a natural isomorphism of the form
$$
\mathsf{SymMonFun}^{\color{blue}{\mathsf{strict}}}(\mathcal{C}\otimes'_\mathbb{F}\mathcal{D},\mathcal{E})
\cong
\mathsf{SymMonFun}^{\mathsf{strong}}(\mathcal{C},\mathsf{SymMonFun}^{\mathsf{strong}}(\mathcal{D},\mathcal{E})).
$$

---

**Question 1.** What is an explicit description of the tensor product $\otimes_{\mathbb{F}}$ making $(1)$ above hold?

**Question 2.** I believe there should be further variants of the tensor product $\otimes_{\mathbb{F}}$, going off two orthogonal directions:

- Replacing $\mathsf{SymMonCats}$ by $\mathsf{2Ab}$, the $2$-category of [abelian $2$-groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_2-group) (also known as [Gr-categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Ho%C3%A0ng+Xu%C3%A2n+S%C3%ADnh) or [Picard groupoids](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24912)), there should be a tensor product $\otimes_{\mathbb{S}}$ whose unit is now given by [the $1$-truncation of the sphere spectrum](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.2686), rather than the groupoid of sets and permutations. The $2$-category $\mathsf{2Ab}$ is to $\mathsf{SymMonCats}$ as $\mathsf{Ab}$ is to $\mathsf{CMon}$.
- Replacing strong monoidal functors (on both sides of $(1)$) by strict, lax, or oplax ones should give tensor products $\otimes^\str_\F$, $\otimes^\lax_\F$, and $\otimes^\oplax_\F$.

Do the tensor products $\otimes_\S$, $\otimes^\str_\S$, $\otimes^\lax_\S$, $\otimes^\oplax_\S$, $\otimes^\str_\F$, $\otimes^\lax_\F$, and $\otimes^\oplax_\F$ indeed exist? If so, what is an explicit description of $\otimes_\S$ and $\otimes^\lax_\F$?

---

(**Why should one care?** Here are two reasons:

1. While semirings and rings are monoids in $(\mathsf{CMon},\otimes_{\mathbb{N}},\mathbb{N})$ and $(\mathsf{Ab},\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}},\mathbb{Z})$, bimonoidal categories and $2$-rings are pseudomonoids in $(\mathsf{SymMonCats},\otimes_{\F},\F)$ and $(\mathsf{2Ab},\otimes_\S,\S)$. (Well, almost: the data is very slightly different (isos instead of monos or just any morphisms) and only $19$ of Laplaza's $22$ axioms hold in the non-symmetric case).
2. Just like

   - The abelian group completion of a commutative monoid is given by $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{N}-$;
   - The $\mathbb{E}_{\infty}$-group completion of an $\mathbb{E}_{\infty}$-space is given by $QS^0\otimes_{\mathbb{F}}-$;
   - The ring completion of a semiring is given by $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{N}-$;

   I suspect the $2$-ring completion functor of [Baas–Dundas–Richter–Rognes](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0531) might be given by $\S\otimes_\F-$, leading to an alternative description of their celebrated construction.)

Comment: I am pretty sure this only works for small symmetric monoidal categories. We need to categorify the construction of tensor products of commutative monoids. Take the free symmetric monoidal category on the product of the underlying categories and freely adjoin the isomorphisms using bicategorical coequalizers and enforce the coherence laws (which you didn't mention) using bicategorical coequifiers. Thus, the universal constructions in https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.10123 will be useful.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thanks, Martin! I asked this on Twitter too, and there Amar Hadzihasanovic [mentioned](https://twitter.com/amar_hh/status/1428961693133152257) their preprint [_The smash product of monoidal theories_](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.10361) and Hackney–Robertson's [_On the category of props_](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2773), giving an outline on adapting the tensor product of PROPs of Hackney–Robertson to get the strict tensor product $\otimes^{\mathsf{str}}_{\mathbb{F}}$.

Comment: I've been planning to read these (and now also your paper, which is really lovely!) and will update the question after that (in particular to mention the coherence laws I forgot about).